# Check the contents of the edit field

Tags: javascript, html

I have on my website `input type="text"` and i trying to write code, that can check when field is empty.

```
if (number>0)document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="+";
else if (number<0)document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="-";
else if (number==0)document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="0";
else document.getElementById("score").innerHTML="this is not a number";
```

And when the field is null, it still shows that "0" is entered.

____edit

```
var number = document.getElementById("field").value;
```

---

```
<input type="text" id="field">
```

Comment: What is `number`?

Comment: Whats the source of your number variable?
In JavaScript if the value of a variable is undefined or null or blank or false then it equals to 0. Always keep that in mind.

Comment: I edited and added additional information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working solution that shows nothing in the `score` div when then input field is empty.  (You can change it to show a message if you want.)

```js
var score = document.getElementById('score');

document.getElementById('field').addEventListener('keyup', checkNum);

function checkNum() {
  var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('field').value);
  if (number>0) score.innerHTML="+";
  else if (number<0) score.innerHTML="-";
  else if (number==0) score.innerHTML="0";
  else if (document.getElementById('field').value=="") score.innerHTML="";
  else score.innerHTML="this is not a number"; 
}
```

```css
#score {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">

<br><br>

<div id="score"></div>
```